# merge result of two queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to combine result of two queries in a way that it should display the result of each ID from both tables separately  and . It should display first ID from both tables and then display the result of second ID. Is there any way to do this?

Suppose I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
Id       Name  
1        ABC  
2        XYZ
```

Table 2:

```
ID quantity Rate
1  30       100  
1  40       400
2  45       800
```

Output should be:

```
1  ABC

1 30 100  
1 40 400

2 XYZ

2 45 800
```

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) The normal approach would be to use `JOIN` and put the name on each row.

Comment: The output you want can not be generated by sql query. If you want to display data like that then you first need to retrieve the data using join and then display it using linq group by.

Comment: A SQL query returns the same number of columns for every row. And every column values must have the same type across all rows. So that display is not possible in SQL. You have to do it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you wanted 2 rows in real like

```
1  ABC  30100
2  XYZ  45800
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.quatity_rate
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: No.. I want the result in separate rows for each ID like result from Ist table in one row for each ID, and then result from 2 table in separate row for same ID

Comment: @SanjayKumar: so it's not possible by one query (you can't merge 2 different datasets). Normally using solution is what I've wrote, select all needed data and then work with them later (in PHP, for example).

Comment: can we do it in separate queries but result should be Collected in separate rows for each ID

Comment: @SanjayKumar: 2 queries are simple, you should make them yourself. And merging data... use any loop to put them  together... I don't know the final format, but it's easy too.